# SKLearn Predicting using new Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've tried out Linear Regression using SKLearn. I have data something along the lines of: Calories Eaten | Weight.

150 | 150

300 | 190

350 | 200

Basically made up numbers but I've fit the dataset into the linear regression model.

**What I'm confused on is, how would I go about predicting with new data, say I got 10 new numbers of Calories Eaten, and I want it to predict Weight?**

```
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test) ??
```

But how would I go about making **only my 10 new data** numbers of Calories Eaten and make it the **Test Set** I want the regressor to predict?

Comment: your question isnt clear, are you confused in generating the numbers or making array?

Comment: Nope. I'm confused on how I would have my model predict the Weight using 10 new numbers of Calorie Eaten.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you simply call the `predict` method of your model and pass in the new unseen data for prediction. Now it also depends on what you mean by `new data`. Are you referencing data that you do not know the outcome of (i.e. you do not know the weight value), or is this data being used to test the performance of your model?

**For new data (to predict on):**

Your approach is correct. You can access all predictions by simply printing the `y_pred` variable.

**You know the respective weight values and you want to evaluate model:**

Make sure that you have two separate data sets: x_test (containing the features) and y_test (containing the labels). Generate the predictions as you are doing with the `y_pred` variable, then you can calculate its performance using a number of performance metrics. Most common one is the root mean square, and you simply pass the `y_test` and `y_pred` as parameters. Here is a list of all the [regression performance metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) supplied by sklearn.

If you do not know the weight value of the 10 new data points:

Use [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to split your initial data set into 2 parts: `training` and `testing`. You would have 4 datasets: `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test`, `y_test`.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# random state can be any number (to ensure same split), and test_size indicates a 25% cut
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(calories_eaten, weight, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
```

Train model by fitting `x_train` and `y_train`. Then evaluate model's training performance by predicting on `x_test` and comparing these `predictions` with the actual results from `y_test`. This way you would have an idea of how the model performs. Furthermore, you can then predict the `weight values` for the `10` new data points accordingly.

It is also worth reading further on the topic as a beginner. [This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/) is a simple tutorial to follow.

Comment: I do know the Weight Values. But how can I make the 10 New Data points x_test? Do I have it read a different csv file?

Comment: If you know the weight values for the 10 new data points, simply pass in the labels as part of the performance metric evaluation. Else, if you do not know the weights for these 10 new points, there is nothing you can do apart for trusting the model's predictions using the performance metrics to guide you. See the edited answer.

Comment: @David, one upvote for your awesome answer. I know the feeling when write a correct and long answer and nobody upvote it in order to recognize the invested time and effort into answering it.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm confused on is, how would I go about predicting with new
>   data, say I got 10 new numbers of Calories Eaten, and I want it to
>   predict Weight?

Yes, `Calories Eaten` represents the independent variable while `Weight` represent `dependent` variable.

After you split the data into training set and test set the next step is to fit the regressor using `X_train` and `y_train` data.

After the model is trained you can predict the results for `X_test` method and so we got the `y_pred`.

Now you can compare `y_pred` (predicted data) with `y_test` which is real data.

You can also use `score` method for your created linear model in order to get the **performance** of your model.

`score` is calculated using `R^2`(R squared) metric or [Coefficient of determination.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

```
score = regressor.score(x_test, y_test)
```

For splitting the data you can use `train_test_split` method.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(eaten, weight, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: Thank You. I'm also confused on how I can make the 10 new data points x_test? Do I call it by reading a different csv file? But then how would the code go to predict?

Comment: @GuiltyVeek, there is already a build in method for this. Have a look to updated answer. You only need to specify the eaten and weight array and specify the test size percent. If you have `100` rows and set `test_size` to `0.2` that means that you will have `80`entries for training and `20` for testing your created model.

Comment: But what if I wanted to only predict the value of weight using 10 new data points that aren't from the original dataset?

Comment: Then you can generate 10 random point with values between min and max from original dataset.

Comment: @GuiltyVeek If you look at the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) for predict, you can see that it takes an `array-like` item. Just put your test values in a list `[1,2,3]` and feed it into the model like you show.

Comment: @patrick, yes, he needed to pass an array, usually it's a numpy array.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Yes, I honestly think that was the OP main source of confusion. Your (very good) answer was maybe more than needed!

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the model using `model_selection` in sklearn then train and fit the dataset.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(eaten, weight)

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```